# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException

Tags: java, apache-poi

In order to read an `xlsx` file I'm using apache POI, I've downloaded the zip and placed the following jsrs in my servlet location `webcontent/web-inf/lib` and configured build path through eclipse

[image]

and my code looks as follows,

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

File uploadedFile = new File(fpath, fileName);
item.write(uploadedFile);
String mimeType = (Files.probeContentType(uploadedFile.toPath())).toString();
System.out.println(mimeType);
if(mimeType.equals("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
{
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(uploadedFile);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    for (int i =0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++)
    {
       XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
       Iterator<Row> row = sheet.iterator();
       while(row.hasNext()) {
   Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = ((Row) row).cellIterator();
       while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
       Cell cell1 = cellIterator.next();
       switch(cell1.getCellType()) 
         {
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
    System.out.print(cell1.getBooleanCellValue() + "\n");
    break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
    System.out.print(cell1.getNumericCellValue() + "\n");
    break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
    System.out.print(cell1.getStringCellValue() + "\n");
    break;
    }
     }
```

Though this does not show and errors on eclipse it shows the following errors when I try to run the code

[image]

What is my mistake? How to solve this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to add the [XML beans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) dependency to your class path.

The library is usually called `xmlbeans-x.x.x.jar`

Comment: Okay. But how to add it in eclipse??

Comment: Manually: get the jar, go to Project, properties, Java build path, add external jar and select the .jar file.

Comment: I have a Swing app working fine, reading Excel files on Windows but on my Linux Virtual Machine, I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException ???? The xmlbeans jar is included.

Answer (score 8):

I have downloaded the latest poi-3.17 binaries and xmlbeans-x.x.x.jar is included in the downloaded package itself.

Attached the screenshots FYR.

[image: Primary jars required for xlsx]
[image: xmlbeans-x.x.x.jar under the folder ooxml-lib]

Answer (score 5):

Add xmlbeans-xpath.jar to your libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you might be trying to produce Office's 2007 format with the POI version for the old formats. Use the `poi-ooxml` jar for the new formats.