# Excel/Word to PDF with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, maven, ms-word, apache-poi

I am testing Apache POI and I have questions.
I am working with maven and java.

1. Is possible convert an excel file to PDF without reading it (Something similar to `PdfConverter.getInstance().convert`)
2. In case there is no function for doing as in step 1, how can I keep the excel styles, formats and others things?
3. Why does this code `PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(doc,outFile,options);` have this error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart (see the code below)?
4. Is there some other library that is FREE that I can use?.

I have attached the pom.xml and the code for the word conversion:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>   

<!-- org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>    

<!-- com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Code for the word conversion:

```
File file1 = new File("myWord.docx");
FileInputStream fileInpStr1 = new FileInputStream(file1.getAbsolutePath());

XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fileInpStr1);
OutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream("myPDFout.pdf"));

PdfOptions options = null;
PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(doc,outFile,options); <-- here the error jumps

outFile.close();
doc.close();
```

Comment: For the classnotfound see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024193/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-xmlbeans-xmloptions

Comment: didn't try by myself, but looks promissing https://github.com/yeokm1/docs-to-pdf-converter

Comment: fr.opensagres.xdocreport does not support poi 4.0.0 - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core/1.0.6 - dependency on poi 3.10-FINAL

Comment: PJ Fanning i add the dependency and change poi version, but i got another error in class XWPFDocument.

Comment: Please take a moment to consult the site's [help] on asking questions. This is a Q&A site, not a "forum". As such, only one question per "Question" is allowed - you ask four. Asking for library or software recommendations is off-topic. You can use the [edit] link under the question to make it conform to Stack Overflow's guidelines.

Comment: The code works perfect but generates a corrupt PDF file.

Answer (score 2):

I've met the same problem while trying to convert word(.docx) to pdf via POI.The error is `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.getPackageRelationship()Lorg/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/PackageRelationshipe`
and I fix this problem by changing POI's version from 3.16 to 3.15(see the dependency below).But I don't think it's the Optimal solution.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>  <-- right version number
        </dependency>
```

So if you resolve this problem by not changing the version,please show me your code.